# Compare time in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, android-timepicker, android-timer

I have two times opening and close. I want to generate as much slot which can be accommodate within defined range with fixed number of minutes. For e.g opening time: 12:30 pm and close timing: 3:30 pm respectively. So in this particular range i have to add minutes let's say 15 min increment every time until the time reaches to close time. Like 12:45, 12:30, ........ , 3:15, 3:30 pm exactly here i want to finish the loop but in my case it goes up to 12:06 am from 12:30 pm

```
        String newTime = "";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(_model.getClinic_time_from());
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        Date date1 = dateFormat1.parse(_model.getClinic_time_to());

        Date temp = date;
        while (date1.compareTo(temp) < 0)
            {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(temp);
                calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(_model.getSlot()));
                newTime = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                Apt_time_model ap = new Apt_time_model(dateFormat.format(temp.getTime()),newTime,"no status");

                    Apt_time_model ap1 = new Apt_time_model(ap.getApt_time_from(), ap.getApt_time_to(),ap.getStatus());
                    list.add(ap1);
                temp = dateFormat.parse(newTime);
            }
```

Comment: 1) Why are you creating two formatters for the same format? Get rid of `dateFormat1`. --- 2) Bad naming: `date`, `date1`, and `temp`. The names don't help identify what they are, so it's too easy to misuse them, as it seems you have. Give them better names, e.g. `fromTime`, `toTime`, and `currTime`. --- 3) `while (date1.compareTo(temp) < 0)` aka `while (toTime.compareTo(currTime) < 0)` makes no sense, since `toTime` by nature will be `> currTime`, so the loop is never executed. --- 4) Don't set `temp` (aka `currTime`) by parsing `newTime`. Use `calendar.getTime()`, which you already called.

Comment: Thank You. Acknowledged!

Comment: Don’t put times as strings in your model. `model.getClinic_time_from()` should return a `LocalTime` and `model.getSlot()` an `int` (also variable names in Java begin with a lower case letter and don’t contain any underscores). Also put `LocalTime` objects into your newly created `AptTimeModel`.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
List < LocalTime > slots = new ArrayList <>();
for ( LocalTime lt = open ; lt.isBefore( close ) ; lt = lt.plusMinutes( 15 ) ) { slots.add( lt ); }
```

> slots.toString(): [12:30, 12:45, 13:00, 13:15, 13:30, 13:45, 14:00, 14:15, 14:30, 14:45, 15:00, 15:15]

## Details

You are using terrible date-date classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. For older Java, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. For older Android, see the *ThreeTenABP* project.

For time-of-day without a date and without a time zone, use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

> 12:30 pm and close timing: 3:30 pm

```
final LocalTime open = LocalTime.of( 12 , 30 );
final LocalTime close = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 );
```

### `while` loop

Loop in 15 minute increments until you reach the close time. Compare by calling `equals`, [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore(java.time.LocalTime)), or `isAfter`.

```
List < LocalTime > slots = new ArrayList <>();
LocalTime lt = open;
while ( lt.isBefore( close ) )
{
    slots.add( lt );
    lt = lt.plusMinutes( 15 );
}

System.out.println( "slots = " + slots );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/IFgUYx).

> slots = [12:30, 12:45, 13:00, 13:15, 13:30, 13:45, 14:00, 14:15, 14:30, 14:45, 15:00, 15:15]

### `for` loop

Some folks might prefer a one-liner `for` loop, for the same effect.

```
List < LocalTime > slots = new ArrayList <>();
for ( LocalTime lt = open ; lt.isBefore( close ) ; lt = lt.plusMinutes( 15 ) ) { slots.add( lt ); }
```

Or:

```
List < LocalTime > slots = new ArrayList <>();
for ( LocalTime lt = open ;
      lt.isBefore( close ) ;
      lt = lt.plusMinutes( 15 ) )
{
    slots.add( lt );
}
```

### Stream

Perhaps there might be some clever way to accomplish this with Java streams. But I cannot think of any.

### Presentation

Generate text representing the meaning within each `LocalTime` object you collected.

Be clear that a `LocalTime` is not a `String`, and a `String` is not a `LocalTime`, but a `String` object can hold text that happens to represent the content of a `LocalTime` object.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US;  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH etc. 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale );
for ( LocalTime slot : slots )
{
    String output = slot.format( f );
    System.out.println( "output = " + output );
}
```

> output = 12:30 PM
>
> output = 12:45 PM
>
> output = 1:00 PM
>
> …

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: Can you tell me how this logic works? (lt.isBefore( close ))

Comment: I'd recommend using a for-each loop, to keep the loop logic together: `for (LocalTime time = open; time.isBefore(close); time = time.plusMinutes(15)) { slots.add(time); }`

Comment: @AzharBhatti Look at the documentation of [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) to see what the various methods do. The method name seems pretty straightforward though: It returns true if the `lt` time *is before* the `close` time.

Comment: After implementing this technique still get the same result

Comment: @AzharBhatti I added a [link to IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/IFgUYx) to prove this code works.

Comment: @Andreas I added the `for` loop per your suggestion.

Comment: @BasilBourque I got it now the problem is your time has 24 - format on the other hand i am working with am/pm. What do you say?

Comment: @AzharBhatti Separate your [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model)  from your presentation strings. Generate objects as shown here. When presenting to the user, use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)) to generate text representing the value within the `LocalTime` objects. The `DateTimeFormatter` class has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.